# How to display the trendline equation on a graph with multiple trendlines in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a graph with 3 trendlines of dependent datasets (with some help), but I need to display the equations and R^2 of these trendlines

|  |
| --- |

```
  concentratie_G6P Inhibitor_Cu_ionen Inhibitor_glucosamine Zonder_inhibitor
1             0.00             0.0019                0.0000           0.0000
2             1.88             0.0448                0.0362           0.0185
3             3.75             0.0134                0.0467           0.0175
4             7.50             0.0470                0.0397           0.0796
5            15.00             0.0285                0.0532           0.0541
6            30.00             0.0324                0.0433           0.0217
```

using the following lines I end up with this figure:

`Zonder_inhibitor<-c(0,0.0185,0.0175,0.0796,0.0541,0.0217)`

`Inhibitor_Cu_ionen <-c(0.0019,0.0448,0.0134,0.0470,0.0285,0.0324)`

`Inhibitor_glucosamine<-c(0,0.0362,0.0467,0.0397,0.0532,0.0433)`

`concentratie_G6P<-c(0,1.88,3.75,7.5,15,30)`

```
tabel_Zonder<-data.frame(concentratie_G6P, Zonder_inhibitor)
tabel_Cu<-data.frame(concentratie_G6P, Zonder_inhibitor)
tabel_glucosamine<-data.frame(concentratie_G6P, Inhibitor_glucosamine)

library("tidyverse")

\`figuur3 \<- ggplot()+  
geom_smooth(data=tabel_Cu, se=FALSE, show.legend = T, fill="black", color = "black" ,aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_Cu_ionen))+
geom_smooth(data = tabel_Zonder, se=FALSE, show.legend=T, fill="red", color="red", aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Zonder_inhibitor))+
geom_smooth(data = tabel_glucosamine, se=FALSE, show.legend=T, fill="blue", aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_glucosamine))+theme_light()+labs(x="concentratie G6P (µM)", y="DA/min")+
geom_point(data = tabel_Cu, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_Cu_ionen, color = "black")) +
geom_point(data = tabel_Zonder, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Zonder_inhibitor, color = "red")) +
geom_point(data = tabel_glucosamine, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_glucosamine, color = "blue"))+
scale_color_manual(
values = c("black", "blue", "red"),
labels =  c("inhibitor Cu-ionen", "inhibitor glucosamine", "zonder inhibitor"))

print(figuur3)\`
```

[image]

How do I display the equations and R^2 of the different trendlines?

Kind regards

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. What is `tabel_cu`, `tabel_Zonder,` etc, etc

Comment: @langtang Oops, I forgot. I have edited my post

Comment: Also, you have those curves are produced using `loess`  - see `?loess` to read about how these are fit.

Answer (score 2):

A few things of note here:

1. It would be easier to convert your wide format data to long format, which much more pleasant to work with in ggplot2.
2. You're fitting a loess model by default. While technically there may be an equation for loess models, they are generally not human readable. I'd recommend to use a standard polynomial model instead, in absence of any kind of information about the data generating process.
3. You're fitting the loess model on 6 datapoints. Loess models are generally for smoothing out noisy data, whereas the problem here is more likely data sparsity, which leaves the modelling prone for overfitting. Think about it this way: do you really believe that at 10 uM, the value is around 0.11 and at 20 uM the value is around 0.01, after which it increases again? The polynomial model will probably still be overfit, but at least it has *some* residual degrees of freedom.

That said, here is how you could display a regression line, equation and R^2 for a polynomial linear regression. (Probably better to use `poly(x, 2)` in the formula though)

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Zonder_inhibitor = c(0,0.0185,0.0175,0.0796,0.0541,0.0217),
  Inhibitor_Cu_ionen = c(0.0019,0.0448,0.0134,0.0470,0.0285,0.0324),
  Inhibitor_glucosamine = c(0,0.0362,0.0467,0.0397,0.0532,0.0433),
  concentratie_G6P = c(0,1.88,3.75,7.5,15,30)
)

# Convert data from wide to long format
long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -concentratie_G6P)

ggplot(long, aes(concentratie_G6P, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, 3),
    se = FALSE, method = lm
  ) +
  ggpubr::stat_regline_equation(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, 3),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  ggpubr::stat_regline_equation(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, 3),
    aes(label = after_stat(rr.label)),
    label.x.npc = "right", hjust = 1,
    show.legend = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Some things went wrong in this experiment, I'm still in my first year of university so the focus of this figure is more on being able to correctly produce a scientific figure. I just wanted to try making the figure using R (making a linear trendline of a limited dataset and displaying the equation/R^2 was easy enough), but I have to conclude I overreached (a lot). I'll have to learn a lot more about the theory behind all of this before jumping in blindly. Anyways thank you a lot for taking your time, have a nice weekend.

Comment: If this experiment is about enzyme kinetics, which I know about, but am not an expert in, you might enjoy [this read](https://rpubs.com/dstoebel/576374) about modelling Michaelis-Menten kinetics. (But, knowing how to handle and display data is a good skill to have regardless of your discipline, so kudos to you for trying this out)

Comment: That's a very interesting link! The assignment is indeed about modeling Michaelis-Menten kinetics (but we did something seriously wrong - potentially with making the dillution series). I do also think handling and displaying data is very important, so this is why I try to learn how to use R for these things (instead of relying on excel).